# Number input allows you to type numbers past the max and min?

Tags: html

With number input, the sliders won't let you go out of the max and min but if you type in a number out of the max and min it still lets you do it. Is there any way to fix this?

HTML:

```
<input id='age' type ='number'  min="0" max='120'/> <br> 
  <label for 'weight'>Your weight:</label>
  <input id='weight' type='number' min='0' max='3000'/> <br> <br>
```

example here, about typing numbers out of the max and min: http://jsbin.com/uwiMeZOq/6/edit

if there is no solution what other kind of input could I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as intended, more or less: the user can type any input, and if it does not meet the requirements, the control is treated as invalid. Form submission will thus fail on supporting browsers, and the element matches the `:invalid` selector, and the situation can be analyzed in JavaScript. The element is *not* meant to physically prevent the user from entering invali input. For that, you would need JavaScript checks and suitable event handlers, basically `onkeypress` and `onpaste`. Even then, the user might be able to enter invalid data via some user interface.

The `input type=number` element is not well suited for input like a person’s age or weight, which have no logical upper bound and which are almost always more easily entered by typing some digits than by using a spinner.

A better approach is to use `input type=text`, possibly with `pattern=\d+`. You could run separate data sensibility checks (with JavaScript), with somewhat larger upper bounds that really cover all known cases.